# Colour picker not working inside modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm unable to get my colour picker to work inside a modal. I've tried changing the z-index and adding the event handlers on modal show. Having a look at the console log and debugging the JavaScript, I can verify that the events are working but the colour values and slider positions are not updating.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-body text-center">
              <div class="color_picker_dialog" draggable="false">
                     <div class="hue_bar">
                          <div class="hue_picker"> </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="sat_rect" draggable="false">
                           <div class="white"></div>
                           <div class="black"></div>
                           <div class="sat_picker"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="bottom">
                           <div class="color_preview"></div>
                       <input type="text" onkeyup="changeHex(this.value)" value="#FF0000" />
                      </div>
                  </div>                      
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A quick example with a working colour picker and the non-working modal version:

> > [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/82925/)

Comment: It's not related to the modal, your javascript only works for one color picker on the page. https://jsfiddle.net/gvs7ko03/

Comment: @Sirence but if you place the only one picker inside the modal it won't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make use of the color picker events inside the modal then you could* initialize the listeners and the picker logic after the modal has been shown.

You can do that by using

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  // ... init all your modal here
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pz2Lams9/

Note, that the above code is not memory-leak save, as there are listeners added each time you show the modal. At this point you may do a revision of your code and rethink the way you connect client components with interaction logic.

**Edit:** you can also make use of `hidden.bs.modal` to unconnect your listeners and flush your variables.

**Readings:**

https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/#events

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events

**Note:**

*I am writing "could" because I am not 100% sure if this is the only way or if there are other ways to solve this, too.

Comment: Thank you! I was adding the event handlers in show.bs.modal.